# Wine installation problem with tableau

Tags: wine

I have licensed version of tableau and I am trying to install it via wine. While installing I am facing below errors. I am not sure on how to resolve them. Can anyone  help ?

```
/media/fountainhop/Osiris$ wine TableauDesktop-64bit-2020-3-3.exe 
003b:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
003b:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
003b:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
003b:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
003b:err:msi:execute_script Execution of script 0 halted; action L"[\"sc.exe\" sdset \"flexnet licensing service 64\" D:(D;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;NU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPWPLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;SY)(A;;CCLCSWRPLOCRRC;;;WD)<=>S-1-5-21-0-0-0-1000<=>{FDFFDD1D-665B-4459-85ED-0F00EE587864}]UpdateFlexNetS"... returned 1603
003b:err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"InstallFinalize" returned 1603
```

Below is my wine version:

```
>>wine --version
wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)
```

I am using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Have the same problem...

Comment: Have you found out the solution?

Comment: I tried a bit but could not do it. Left it for pros to figure out